# cookies: every 2 Monday (every 2 week)

Tags: php, date, cookies

what I'm trying to achieve is to get the date of the **next next Monday**, but only the pair Monday of the year, for example this year (2014) the first Monday is 6th Jan -> (after 2 weeks)-> 20th Jan.

I want to launch a competition every 2 weeks (every 2 Monday) and I want to set cookie to expire in the first minute of the 3rd Monday to let the customer to see the competition popup again.

I tried to find a solution in the web but no luck, I don't think it's a common situation

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you already have the dates that each competition starts and you want to calculate when it ends (i.e. two weeks after it starts)? Do you want to calculate all the competition end and start dates for a given year or month? If that's the case, you' re saying that you want to run a competition every two weeks, from the 1st Monday of the month to the 3rd Monday of the month, but what about months that have 5 weeks (e.g. March 2014)? Will you just ignore the 5th week and start over from the 1st Monday of next month?

Comment: @StathisG I have one competition popup, and we run competition every 2 weeks (starting from Monday) usign the same popup over and over, I do not have date start or end (it would be easy if I have one of these) so cookie must expire in the 3rd week, 5th week, 7th week always every Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the first contest starts at the first Monday of the current year (i.e. the year of the date you're providing to the function), I believe the following should work properly:

```
function get_next_contest_date($current_date) {
    $current_date_obj = new DateTime($current_date);

    $year = $current_date_obj->format("Y");
    $first_day_of_year = date('D', strtotime("$year-01-01"));

    $week = $current_date_obj->format("W");
    $contest_week = $week;

    if($first_day_of_year !== 'Mon') {
        $contest_week--;
    }

    $end_date_obj = new DateTime();

    if($contest_week & 1) {
        $end_date_obj->setISODate($year, $week + 2);
    } else {
        $end_date_obj->setISODate($year, $week + 1);
    }

    return $end_date_obj->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Kv74zD

Note: If you provide a date which is earlier than the first contest's date, for example `2014-01-03`, it will return the first contest's date, i.e. `2014-01-06`;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to calculate the first Monday of a given year, then calculate the dates of every second Monday of that year thereafter.  If that's the case, here is a short snippet of code that will do that:

```
<?
$year=2014;
$d="01-01-" . $year;
$i=date("w", strtotime($d));
if($i==0) { $FirstMondayOfTheYear="02-01-" . $year; }
if($i==1) { $FirstMondayOfTheYear="01-01-" . $year; }
if($i>=2) { $j=9-$i; $FirstMondayOfTheYear="0" . $j . "-01-" . $year; }

$d=$FirstMondayOfTheYear;
while( date("Y", strtotime($d))==$year ) {
  print date("D d-m-Y", strtotime($d)) . "\n";
  $d=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($d . "+14 days"));
}
?>
```

Comment: that's not what I was looking for, I need to get the date of the next next Monday based on the current date and the previous 2 Mondays

Comment: You can pretty much use the logic above.  Just add some logic inside the loop to check when you are past the current date.